# Datagridview doesn't return the id of row

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datagridview

I insert a gridview into my project,i put a button to get the id of clicked row but everytime it returns "0" value .

```
 if (e.CommandName == "editrecord")
        {

            int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
            GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[index];

            txtBrand.Text = row.Cells[0].Text;

        }
```

Here is my gridview code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="SubProductId" HeaderText="شماره " />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="برند ">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SubProductName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SubProductName") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Image" CommandName="editrecord" HeaderText="ویرایش" ImageUrl="~/adminPortal/Images/edit.png" />
        </Columns>
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: I finally found the problem is because of "EditItemTemplate" when i removed that it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found, the problem is because of "EditItemTemplate" when i removed that it works